# rsync to report file size using `--out-format`

Tags: rsync

I would like `rsync` to report the file size at the source location for all files being reported when I use `--itemize-changes` or `--out-format`. For example, I know I can use the following format, `"%i %f"`, to provide the type of change and the file name; however, I cannot find the correct escape code for file size. I tried `%b` but seem that related to bytes transferred and reports `0` for files that are not being changed.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be what you are looking for:

> `%l`   the length of the file in bytes

(That's a lower case `L`.)

Source: https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsyncd.conf.html
or [`man 5 rsyncd.conf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/rsyncd.conf.5.html).

Comment: thanks. Do you have source that explains what the various escape codes mean?

Comment: Fount it here: https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsyncd.conf.html